# JMETER - How to manage Cache buster

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Hope everyone is doing well and busy in their stuff and assignments :-)

I am facing some issue to manage cachebuster which is passing as Query String Parameter in one of my product end point

`**/configuration/getProgramNameInfo/224814?cachebuster=85926591608949220`

The Problem is that it is not coming in any response and for each endpoint it is changing. Seems because of this, I am not getting correct response from Subsequent requests

Can anyone help here, How to manage cachebuster in JMETER

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this "cachebuster" is some form of a [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/) library which scans for particular tags and adds some postifx to them like [this one](https://codekitapp.com/help/cache-buster/)

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So if you want to fully simulate the browser's behaviour you need to replicate this JavaScript logic in JMeter's [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) in [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) language.

If you want to just send "something" you can go for [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) function  like:

```
/configuration/getProgramNameInfo/224814?cachebuster=${__RandomString(17,0123456789,)}
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T.

Since /configuration/getProgramNameInfo/224814?cachebuster=${__RandomString(17,0123456789,)}   is not working as Solution. 

Still working and Looking some workaround :-)